# Inconsistent heights with date and select

Tags: html, css, forms

I have come across this issue and not sure of resolution. These 2 inputs should be coming in exactly the same height, however they are not. After looking at similar questions exhaustively, I've confirmed this is not due to box-sizing. Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the issue in question:
[image: The calendar input's bottom border is lower than the select input's.]

```css
.updateInput select {
  width: calc(24.5% - 4px);
  min-height: 1.5em;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 14px;
  min-height: 1.5em;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.updateInput input[type=date] {
  width: calc(24.5% - 4px);
}

input[type=number],
input[type=date] {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 14px;
}

input {
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 1.5em;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="saleUpdateInput" class="updateInput">
  <form id="updateInputData">
    <select>
      <option selected>Select product</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option selected>Select sale %</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date">
    <input type=submit value="Update">
  </form>
</div>
```

Minimal example as requested in comments:
https://jsfiddle.net/8qexLpa3/

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your problem.

Comment: @CBroe added example as requested 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice by default `display:inline-block` aligns selects to the top of the container and inputs to the bottom.

```html
<div id="saleUpdateInput" class="updateInput">
  <form id="updateInputData">
    <select>
      <option selected>Select product</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option selected>Select sale %</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date">
    <input type=submit value="Update">
  </form>
</div>
```

I would recommend you use flex box to take control over this behavior.

```css
#updateInputData {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="saleUpdateInput" class="updateInput">
  <form id="updateInputData">
    <select>
      <option selected>Select product</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option selected>Select sale %</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date">
    <input type=submit value="Update">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently using chrome, however this is coming up in other browsers too? Also if I run your code snippet I get the same result as the issue I've noted?

Comment: After testing in Chrome I can see the issue. I made some recommendations above.